# Is Google cloud messaging instanceID permanent or temporarly?

Tags: android, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

I am creating a messenger app using google cloud messaging and i just thought of using the token from instanceID to identify the users,but for some unknown reason the first token i got from this method

`InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
        GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);`

is not as same as the token i am getting from the server using "from" tag like this.

```
    public void handleIncomingDataMessage(Map<String, Object> jsonObject) {

    String from = jsonObject.get("from").toString(); }
```

i just need to know that is this a problem with my coding or is it really changing and i cant rely on the token anymore.

Comment: There are many rules applied for the GCM, better is to get more info from : https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Comment: yeah,i read that but i just need to know can i use this token as a unique identifier or not? because i read somewhere its unique and not changing until  you decide to change it but it looks like google is changing it frequently.

Comment: Yes, the Registration ID returned from the GCM is unique until you un-registered the device, or an upper limit of device is passed.

Comment: but it appears its changing time to time as of  example i have given above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instance ID is indeed supposed to be constant, as described here: 
[What is Instance ID?](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/)

However, there is two important points to note:

- Make sure you do not call `getID()` method somewhere in your code. It is intended to get a new fresh token.
- Google can decide to force update it for security reason. You have to handle that case: "Your app must implement a listener to respond to token refresh requests from the Instance ID service."

Comment: thank you for your comment,yeah as you mentioned, there are possible situations it can be change so it is not a good identifier to identify a user uniquely,so i'm getting rid of this and will implement my own string to identify users

Answer (score 0):

(I don't know English)
Call again this code:

```
String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

the new token will be generate and it will be not equal the old token you have fetch  to server before.

Comment: i don't want to call again this method. i just need to clarify the token is unique and not changing from request to request